# Is there anyway to do specific task in build task?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to copy sub modules archive files into root project build directory while running root project's build task

```
task archive(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn copyWars

    archiveName = "${project.name}-${version}.zip"
    destinationDir = file('build/dist')
    from 'build/libs'
    exclude "*.zip"
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

I've already tried with `build.dependsOn archive` and `build.finalizedBy archive`

I want root module zip file containing sub modules war file while running root module build task. 
Let a,b two sub modules and c is the root module. So `c.zip` should contain `a.war` & `b.war`. But no `c.zip` file is created.
May be I'm doing wrong approach.
Please anyone show me the right path.

Comment: Could you describe your desired output and the output you get?

Comment: @LukasKörfer I've edited my post

Comment: What is the console output of the Gradle invocations?

Comment: @LukasKörfer console output showing BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: Your task `archive` seems correct (except the use of some deprecated properties), and `build.dependsOn archive` is a good way to create the needed dependency. The issue might reside in your `copyWars` task definition, please provide code of this task in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two sub-projects `war1` and `war2` which produce `war` artefact: the following configuration in the Root project's script should work:

*build.gradle* (root project)

```
// copy war artifacts from sub-projects
task copyWars(type: Copy){
    into "build/libs"
    from project("war1").war
    from project("war2").war
}

// create archive with content from  'build/libs' directory
task archive(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn copyWars
    archiveName  = "${project.name}-${version}.zip"
    destinationDir  = file('build/dist')
    from 'build/libs'
    exclude "*.zip"
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
// add 'archive' task to the main "build" lifecycle
build.dependsOn archive
```

You could also simplify and get rid of the `copyWars` (if this task purpose is only to copy wars from subprojects to root project):

```
task archive(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn copyWars
    archiveName  = "${project.name}-${version}.zip"
    destinationDir  = file('build/dist')
    from 'build/libs'
    from project("war1").war
    from project("war2").war        
    exclude "*.zip"
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
build.dependsOn archive
```